# Net force exerted by pressure

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, pressure

Why do the net force $K$ exerted by the pressure of
a hard sphere gas according to the Maxwellian distribution on the walls of the container
$A \subset R^3$ vanishes? (In the absence of external fields and regardless of the shape of $A$).

Maybe I should to use the equation of state??

Comment: Do you mean the hard spheres are inside some 3D container and those spheres are colliding with the container walls from within?  If so, is there a net "wind" inside the container?  If not, are there more spheres hitting one wall over all the others?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.